# Interface, base class or what?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm having a slight misfunction of my brain here.

Say I have a report page that can contain either a graph, or a datatable. But the page has several components in common, like header, page number, generic report information and such.

Right now I have made a PageBase-class with the common data fields, and i have a PageGraph class and a PageTable class that both inherit from the baseclass. (I also created an IPage interface, but VS/R# tells me it's redundant because all the fields are included in the base-class)

My code looks something like this:

```
var data = new List<IPage>();
pageItems.Where().OrderBy().ForEach(pageData => {
  var page = pageData.PageType == 0 ? new PageGraph() : new PageTable(); // <- this one errs out.
  page.header = pageData.header;
  page.pageNumber = someCounter;
  page.otherMetaData = pageData.otherMetaData;
  if (pageData.PageType == PageTypes.Graph) {
    // Fill graph fields etc.
    ...
```

How can I instantiate the correct class based on the pageData.PageType variable?

The language is C#.

Comment: What are you filling `PageXxx` from? What is the difference between the initialization of the two page types? What are you having these classes for? Etc. Consider making the graph/table a separate object and holding a reference to it from the page object. Inheritance is less often useful than it seems to be.

Comment: I'm getting "There is no implicit conversion between PageTable and PageGraph"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if

```
var page = pageData.PageType == 0 ? new PageGraph() : new PageTable();
```

is erroring out its problably because they compiler can't figure out which class page needs to be. If the PageGraph and PageTable both inhert from PageBase then perhaps this should work.

```
PageBase page = pageData.PageType == 0 ? (PageBase)(new PageGraph()) : (PageBase)(new PageTable());
```

once you have the base class you can then strongly cast it in the places you need assuming that

```
 if (pageData.PageType == PageTypes.Graph) {
    // Fill graph fields etc.
```

is where you need the specific class properties then you could do

```
 if (pageData.PageType == PageTypes.Graph) {
    // Fill graph fields etc.
    var stonglyCastPage = (PageGraph)page;
    ...
```

for example

Comment: I get the "There is no implicit conversion between PageTable and PageGraph" on both of those.

Comment: The casting fixes the errors when instantiating. But I still can't access the PageGraph or PageTable specific properties. (The ``page`` object is still PageBase)

Comment: Aaaaaand it's yours! *highfive* (Until everything blows up and I'll be  coming back to blame everything on you)

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Warrenn enslin does not work. Use the following:

```
PageBase page = pageData.PageType == 0 ? (PageBase)new PageGraph() : new PageTable();
```

Comment: sorry only saw it after I posted

Comment: As long as Christian gets his answer!